# RobotFramework: Date format conversion issue

Tags: robotframework, date-format

I am not sure what is going wrong here. I have given a time to convert, the format of the time, and the result format, like so:

```
${date_to_search_for}=  Convert Date  2017-06-14 13:03:02.506610  date_format=%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.00000  result_format=%d %b %Y 00:00:00  exclude_millis=True
Log to console  ${date_to_search_for}
```

Running this code, presents this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-06-14 13:03:02.506610' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.00000'
```

I have checked both formats closely and cannot see a difference! I don't understand why it is throwing this error.

Answer (score 5):

The date you have given Robot:

```
2017-06-14 13:03:02.506610
```

Is not the format you are saying it is

```
date_format=%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.00000
```

Please use the Python Formatting of DateTime like so:

```
${date_to_search_for}=    Convert Date    2017-06-14 13:03:02.506610    date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f     result_format=%d %b %Y 00:00:00    exclude_millis=True
Log to console  ${date_to_search_for}
```

Note the `%H:%M:%S.%f` for your time requirements.

```
%H = 24 Hour Hour Time
%M = Minute with leading 0
%S = seconds with leading 0
%f = microseconds with leading 0
```

All can be found [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

This will result in the following format to be logged:

```
${date_to_search_for} = 14 Jun 2017 00:00:00
```

Any problems please ask :)

Comment: Ah man sorry about that, blonde day. In my defence no coffee yet. Thanks

Comment: No problem mate, happens to us all! :D

Comment: Wait...still getting one issue   ValueError: time data '2017-06-14 13:03:02.506610' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000000'

Comment: Let me check for you - Ill set up Robot on my machine, give me a few minutes and ill sort it for you